# RE: Compiling OpenCV4.3.0 with GCC 8.3.0-1 on Debian Buster

Tags: opencv, makefile, cmake, compilation

First, I listed this info. on the OpenCV.org site at https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html.

Secondly, I used my git source to use this command: `git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git`

Thirdly, I used these commands to try to build the OpenCV version of 4.3.0.

```
cd opencv/opencv4.3.0
mkdir build && cd build

cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DWITH_TBB=ON
-DBUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -DWITH_V4L=ON
-DINSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -DINSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON
-DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -DWITH_QT=OFF -DWITH_OPENGL=ON ../

make
```

In the /build directory, I keep getting kicked out of my session at 71% or my Linux SBC looses online Internet via WiFi at that percentage. Do you see an issue with my cmake command? Do you know or have you seen any issues pertaining to losing control of your Linux SBC during the make command on your side?

Comment: If it kicks out of your session then also it should give a message. Can you share that error with us ? Or it is freezing at 71% ?

Comment: Hello...it does not give a message but the terminal session via PuTTY on Win 10 shows the board disconnected from the USB interface to the computer.